# Determine unique dictionary keys across rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, loops, dictionary

I have a dataframe where every row is a dictionary, however the keys in each dictionary vary. I would like to iterate over each row and get one list with all unique keys. Does anyone know how to do this?

I tried this code

```
np.unique(np.array(train.totals.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x).keys())))
```

But this yields unique combinations of dict_keys(), not unique combinations of keys.

For example, lets say I have two rows. As mentioned above, the column values for each row are a dictionary. The dictionary keys for row 1 are fruit and vegetable, and the dictionary keys for row 2 are fruit, vegetable and grain.

The code above would produce

```
dict_keys(['fruit','vegetable'])
```

and

```
dict_keys(['fruit','vegetable','grain'])
```

However, what I am want the output to be is just a list or array with fruit, vegetable and grain (the unique keys seen across rows).

Edit: screenshot of dataframe added[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvJ0c.png)

edit2: Code sample below

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import ast

dummy_data = [['A',str({"pageviews":"1","hits":"1"})],['B',str({"pageviews":"1","visits":"1"})]]
dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data,columns = ['ID','totals'])

np.unique(np.array(dummy_df.totals.apply(lambda x: ast.literal_eval(x).keys())))
```

Comment: Can you include some code to generate your df, or a MCVE?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.  
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: "I have a dataframe where every row is a dictionary" probably not a good design choice. Since you've pretty much removed any chance of doing this efficiently, just iterate over each row, and add all the keys to a `set`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I was trying to do that, but I couldn't figure out how to get a `df` of dictionaries. I kept just getting a flat dataframe. :-/

Comment: @juanpa dataset is not mine, provided by third party ;)

Comment: @evan Attached a code snippit that should reproduce the output I am currently getting, which are the unique keys for each row. What I am trying to get is just a list of all unique keys across rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just iterate and add to a set:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
   ...: import numpy as np
   ...: import ast
   ...:
   ...: dummy_data = [['A',str({"pageviews":"1","hits":"1"})],['B',str({"pageviews":"1","visits":"1"})]]
   ...: dummy_df = pd.DataFrame(dummy_data,columns = ['ID','totals'])
   ...:
   ...:

In [2]: dummy_df
Out[2]:
  ID                             totals
0  A    {'pageviews': '1', 'hits': '1'}
1  B  {'pageviews': '1', 'visits': '1'}

In [3]: uniq = set()
   ...: for x in dummy_df.totals:
   ...:     uniq.update(ast.literal_eval(x))
   ...:

In [4]: uniq
Out[4]: {'hits', 'pageviews', 'visits'}
```

Probably the best you can do given the structure of your data.